# Bloc Provider not available for screen it is pushed to

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to make the same AccountBloc available PersonalInformation(Screen push after pressing button in Home Screen).

Is there any method too make this possible?

[image]

I tried to add AccountBloc at top of screen with NetworkBloc but the problem with this method is this will not delete the state of AccountBloc even if I switch account.

So is there any method to make AccountBloc available to PersonalInformation?

If it is not possible, is there any method to delete state of AccountBloc when I switch account?

Comment: how you are navigating to the account information page

Comment: By this code: Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("route_name")

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed my problem with BlocProvider.value().